# How to match 'any' parameter type while mocking private method in Jmockit

Tags: jmockit, private-methods, partial-mocks

I have a problem while using jmockit for the following scenario. Did a research on the web, but couldn't locate the answers yet.

In the record phase, I am setting the expectation on an object that is partially mocked. While doing it, I would like to mock a private method with single parameter. But i don't really concerned with that parameter value. I want to match all invocation of that particular private method with any instance of argument passed to it. How do I do it in Jmockit. Is there a way?

```
new Expectations(student) {
    {
        Deencapsulation.invoke(student, "setDepartment", (Department) any);
        result = new Delegate<Student>() {
            public void setDepartment(Department dept) {
                System.out.println("Mocked setDepartment() methodd.....");
            }
        };
    }
};
```

In the above code, `(Department) any` can not be passed, since `Deencapsulation.invoke(...)` method doesn't accept `null` value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the [API documentation](http://jmockit.github.io/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#any) for the `any` field says:

"In invocations to non-accessible methods or constructors (for example, with Deencapsulation.invoke(Object, String, Object...)), use withAny(T) instead."

That is, you need to use `withAny(Department.class)` with the `invoke(...)` call.

Answer (score 0):

As of JMockit v1.49, I use:

```
withInstanceOf(Department.class)
```

It works as expected.